# Getting an embedded table in room android sqlite3 query

Tags: android, mysql, sqlite, android-room

I have the following query

```
@Query("SELECT DBITM.ItemNumber, DBITM.Description, DBCRI.SuggestedQty, DBCRI.WTDSalesQty, DBCRI.DemandQty, DBITM.UnitsPerCase, DBCST.SuggestSalesFlag " + 
        "FROM DBCST" +
        "INNER JOIN DBCRI ON DBCRI.CustomerNumber = :customerNumber and DBCST.CustomerNumber = :customerNumber " +
        "INNER JOIN DBITM ON DBITM.ItemNumber = DBCRI.ItemNumber ")
```

The above query gives me a

```
List<MyPojo>
```

However NOW MyPojo will have an embedded Object of BatchDetails like so

```
public int ItemNumber;
public String Description;
public float SuggestedQty;
public float WTDSalesQty;
public int DemandQty;
public int UnitsPerCase;
public int SuggestSalesFlag;
public int BatchEntryEnabled;
public List<BatchDetails> BatchDetails;//This will have the batch details
```

I want to query all the batch details only for the ItemNumber available in the DBITM.ItemNumber(from above query) that matches DBBTC.ItemNumber(BatchDetails table) if there is no matching ItemNumber the BatchDetails in the MyPojo should either be filled with default values or could be null(which ever is quicker in query).

Please provide me the raw sqlite query to do the above operation.

Comment: Are you asking for help with the query, or with the Java side of things?  Note that your raw query isn't just returning a single entity; it's returning fields from multiple entities.

Comment: Are you asking for help with the query ?
YES.
Note that your raw query isn't just returning a single entity; it's returning fields from multiple entities
Yes, I am aware of that

Comment: No...that's what _I_ was asking _you_.  Are you asking for help with the SQL itself, or with the Java code?